# How to remove additional index when using .mean(), .median(), .mode() in python on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, mean, median, mode

I am calculating the mode/median/mean of pandas df columns using .mean(), .median(), .mode() but when doing so an index appears in some of the results:

```
def largeStats(dataframe):
    dataframe.drop(dataframe.index[dataframe['large_airport'] != 'Y'], inplace=True)
    mean = dataframe['frequency_mhz'].mean()
    mode = dataframe['frequency_mhz'].mode()
    median = dataframe['frequency_mhz'].median()

    print("The mean freq of large airports is", mean)
    print("The most common freq of large airports is", mode)
    print("The middle freq of large airports is", median)

print(largeStats(df))
```

returns:

```
The mean freq of large airports is 120.00752293577986
The most common freq of large airports is 0    121.75
1    122.10
dtype: float64
The middle freq of large airports is 121.85
None
```

I want it to simply return the number for each:

> The mean freq of large airports is 120.00752293577986

> The most common freq of large airports is 121.75 & 122.10

> The middle freq of large airports is 121.85

I know the indexing is in place due to 2 mode values but how would I remove that indexing?

Answer (score 2):

This would fix it,

```
mode = dataframe['frequency_mhz'].mode().values[0]
```

The `mode()` function gives back a pandas series. So this would allow you to access the item in that series.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a pandas into a numpy array using the `.values` property:

```
mode = dataframe['frequency_mhz'].mode().values
```

should give you what you want.

Comment: This would return something like **"The most common freq of large airports is [<mode value>]"**. But if you do `.values[0]`, it would fix it!

Comment: He wants both values for the mode, you suggestion would give only one.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) can return one or more values, need filter first value for scalar:

> The mode is the value that appears most often. There can be multiple modes.

```
print("The most common freq of large airports is", mode.iat[0])
```